# Add KML file to map already created api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to add a KML file polygons to a map already created with their respective markers, with no apparent result.
It's possible?
For me it only works one way or the other.
URL KML file is located at the end of post.

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
    ['0', 'CLI23456', -18.498682, -70.294426, 'as'],
    ['1', 'CLI12345', -18.499508, -70.295250, 'ap'],
    ['2', 'CLI78912', -18.497622, -70.293671, 'as'],
    ['3', 'CLI54321', -18.472946, -70.295662, 'pvp']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.476202, -70.307236);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(13);
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */

filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Seleccionar categoría</option>
    <option value="as">AS</option>
    <option value="ap">AP</option>
    <option value="pvp">PVP</option>
</select>
```

KML file polygons: [My KML file polygons](http://redeslibres.cl/documentos/kml/SECTOR_AS.kml)

Comment: [Your KML doesn't validate](http://www.feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fredeslibres.cl%2Fdocumentos%2Fkml%2FSECTOR_AS.kml), but the [data displays using KmlLayer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://redeslibres.cl/documentos/kml/SECTOR_AS.kml)

Answer (score 0):

You should use  a kmlLayer

```
var map;

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.476202, -70.307236);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }


    var mykmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'http://redeslibres.cl/documentos/kml/SECTOR_AS.kml',
          map: map
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
The problem was where I was part, as my project is much more complex than the example presented.
You solution is 100% satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

The native Google Maps Javascript KML renderer is [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml).

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://redeslibres.cl/documentos/kml/SECTOR_AS.kml',
  map: map
});
```

To prevent that from "auto-zooming" to fit the KML, use the `preserveViewport: true` option.

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://redeslibres.cl/documentos/kml/SECTOR_AS.kml',
  map: map,
  preserveViewport: true // prevent zoom from changing to fit KML
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
  ['0', 'CLI23456', -18.498682, -70.294426, 'as'],
  ['1', 'CLI12345', -18.499508, -70.295250, 'ap'],
  ['2', 'CLI78912', -18.497622, -70.293671, 'as'],
  ['3', 'CLI54321', -18.472946, -70.295662, 'pvp']
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */
function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.476202, -70.307236);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://redeslibres.cl/documentos/kml/SECTOR_AS.kml',
    map: map,
    preserveViewport: true // prevent zoom from changing to fit KML
  });

  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers1[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */
function addMarker(marker) {
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[1];
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
  var content = marker[1];
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: title,
    position: pos,
    category: category,
    map: map
  });
  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
      map.setZoom(13);
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */
filterMarkers = function(category) {
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
      marker.setVisible(true);
    }
    // Categories don't match 
    else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
  <option value="">Seleccionar categoría</option>
  <option value="as">AS</option>
  <option value="ap">AP</option>
  <option value="pvp">PVP</option>
</select>
```